# flutter app not work correctly in release mode

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, apk, release

i have a flutter app, and its work perfectly in debug mode , but when run in release mode, it is work but doesn't fetch the data from firestore, and there is no error message or anything.... this is the method for fetch data :

```
 Future<List<SectionModel>?> showSections() async {
    var userInfo = await udb.getUserInfo();
    List<String> userCode = userInfo != null ? userInfo.codes : [];
    List<SectionModel> sections = [];
    try {
      var sectionInfo = await _coursesCollection.where("sectionCode", whereIn: userCode).get();
      var data = sectionInfo.docs
          .map((section) => SectionModel?.fromMap(section.data()))
          .toList();
      if(data.isNotEmpty) {
        sections = data;
        return sections;
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      Warnings.showSnackBar(
          "db problem", "could not fetch the section information !!");
    }
  }
```

only in release mode, app show me this message in Snackbar : "db problem", "could not fetch the section information !!....

and this is the security rules in firestore, and i have used phone authentication in my app:

```
rules_version = '2';
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

this is a part of what i have found in Logcat (Errors):

```
2021-06-18 12:33:06.441 3945-4040/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2021-06-18 12:33:06.547 3844-23251/? E/AudioFlinger: stageIndex is 0, get default sink buf
2021-06-18 12:33:07.751 4308-4417/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1
2021-06-18 12:33:15.066 4308-4935/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2751 [2021-06-18 12:33:15.065] FD count : 563
2021-06-18 12:33:17.617 14880-27368/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-06-18 12:33:18.181 4308-4417/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1
2021-06-18 12:33:45.084 4308-4935/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2752 [2021-06-18 12:33:45.084] FD count : 563
2021-06-18 12:34:06.445 3945-4040/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2021-06-18 12:34:15.098 4308-4935/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2753 [2021-06-18 12:34:15.098] FD count : 563
2021-06-18 12:34:28.091 327-327/? E/fb4a.MsysMqttTopicsProvider: subscribing to mqtt
2021-06-18 12:34:29.899 15003-23169/? E/AuthPII: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: Account {name=osama@itdar.com, type=com.google}, App: com.android.vending, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googleplay
    uto: Long live credential not available.
        at hnx.a(:com.google.android.gms@212116028@21.21.16 (100400-378233385):13)
        at hoa.e(:com.google.android.gms@212116028@21.21.16 (100400-378233385):1)
        at hml.l(:com.google.android.gms@212116028@21.21.16 (100400-378233385):44)
```

Comment: I think instead of showing "db problem" you have to show the exception "e". from this you get the actual error.

Comment: As @RajniGujarati said at first you need to find actual problem by printing the e. also make sure you have added internet permission in android manifest file

Comment: i have added internet permission, and this what (e) show: I/flutter ( 3346): [cloud_firestore/unknown] An error occurred while parsing query arguments, see native logs for more information. Please report this issue.

Comment: the native logs can be seen with logcat. Try to take a look at those, maybe some useful information can be found there

Comment: i have seen it, but could not understand anything, i added it in the question